# PostgreSQL - Select only 1 row for each ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

**SITUATION**

I am working on a travel engine site and am writing a complex query to match visitors' search queries with their bookings based on **IP Address**, **Destination** and **Date** so I can work out the conversion ratio later.

**PROBLEM**

There needs to be multiple conversion ratios based on a parameter (In this case, the **utm_source** which I extract from a **RequestUrl** stored in the searches table). The problem is some users make multiple searches from different locations.. sometimes we get the **utm_source** in the request and sometimes not... and of course we need to match to only 1 booking. See screenshot of query result below to better understand:

[image]

See the 3rd and 4th rows have the same booking ID, etc.. but different values for the **Value** column. I need to select only 1 of these, but not both. Basically, if there is more than 1, I need to choose the 1 that is not "N/A".

**MY QUERY:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT "B"."Id" AS "BookingId", "PQ"."IPAddress", "PQ"."To", "PQ"."SearchDate", "PQ"."Value"
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT "IPAddress", "To", "CreatedAt"::date AS "SearchDate", COALESCE(SUBSTRING("RequestUrl", 'utm_source=([^&]*)'), 'N/A') AS "Value"
    FROM dbo."PackageQueries"
    WHERE "SiteId" = '<The ID>'
    AND "CreatedAt" >= '<Start Date>'
    AND "CreatedAt" < '<End Date>'
) AS "PQ"
INNER JOIN dbo."Bookings" AS "B"
    ON "PQ"."IPAddress" = "B"."IPAddress"
    AND "B"."To" = "PQ"."To"
    AND "B"."BookingDate"::date = "PQ"."SearchDate"
WHERE "B"."SiteId" = '<The ID>'
AND "B"."BookingStatus" = 2
AND "B"."BookingDate" >= '<Start Date>'
AND "B"."BookingDate" < '<End Date>'
ORDER BY "B"."Id", "PQ"."IPAddress", "PQ"."To";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thank you for the link.. and not so much for the downvote.  :-D . This is a slightly more complex situation than those. For one, I can't just order by some readily available integer or date/time value and as such I don't think it was worthy of a down-vote.. but so be it. I did find a solution and I will be posting my own answer in a moment...

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, My apologies.. I assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and based it on what I found here: [Return rows that are max of one column in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858657/return-rows-that-are-max-of-one-column-in-postgresql) and here: [Postgres CASE in ORDER BY using an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298421/postgres-case-in-order-by-using-an-alias)

My solution is as follows:

```
SELECT "BookingId", "IPAddress", "To", "SearchDate", "Value"
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        "B"."Id" AS "BookingId",
        "PQ"."IPAddress",
        "PQ"."To",
        "PQ"."SearchDate",
        "PQ"."Value",
        RANK() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY "B"."Id"
            ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN "PQ"."Value" = 'N/A' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS "RowNumber"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT "IPAddress", "To", "CreatedAt"::date AS "SearchDate", COALESCE(SUBSTRING("RequestUrl", 'utm_source=([^&]*)'), 'N/A') AS "Value"
        FROM dbo."PackageQueries"
        WHERE "SiteId" = '<Site ID>'
        AND "CreatedAt" >= '<Start Date>'
        AND "CreatedAt" < '<End Date>'
    ) AS "PQ"
    INNER JOIN dbo."Bookings" AS "B"
        ON "PQ"."IPAddress" = "B"."IPAddress"
        AND "B"."To" = "PQ"."To"
        AND "B"."BookingDate"::date = "PQ"."SearchDate"
    WHERE "B"."SiteId" = '<Site ID>'
    AND "B"."BookingStatus" = 2
    AND "B"."BookingDate" >= '<Start Date>'
    AND "B"."BookingDate" < '<End Date>'
) T
WHERE "RowNumber" = 1
ORDER BY "BookingId", "IPAddress", "To";
```

Somewhat long-winded, but it does the trick nicely. I hope it helps others.

**EDIT**

This wasn't the end of the story: there were still some cases in which I was getting more than 1 value. The answer was to modify the CASE statement to generate a unique number for each text value. The solution can be found here: [PostgreSQL - Assign integer value to string in case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148956/postgresql-assign-integer-value-to-string-in-case-statement/42150221?noredirect=1#42150221)