# PostgreSQL - ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why am I getting the following error?:

**ERROR:  query has no destination for result data**

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.SumASCII(
    value character varying)
    RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $function$

    DECLARE finalResult int;
    DECLARE tempChar character;
    DECLARE valueLength int;
    DECLARE tempResult int;

    BEGIN
        SELECT LENGTH(value) INTO valueLength;
        SELECT finalResult = 0;
        SELECT tempResult = 0;

        DO
        $do$
        BEGIN 
        FOR i IN 1..valueLength LOOP
           SELECT SUBSTRING(value, i, 1) INTO tempChar;
           SELECT ASCII(tempChar) INTO tempResult;
           SELECT finalResult += tempResult;
        END LOOP;
        END
        $do$;

        RETURN finalResult;
    END;

$function$;
```

I've looked at other questions with the same error, but they don't seem to be related to my problem. I'm sure the answer is simple, but I just can't seem to see what the issue is here.. I'm declaring an int and I am returning an int..

Calling the function as follows:

```
SELECT SumASCII('abc')
```

Comment: using DO statement inside plpgsql is nonsense. Newer use SELECT instead assign statement `:=`.

Comment: The selects are completely unnecessary: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by simplifying a lot. I believe `DECLARE` just needs to be used once (examples at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-declarations.html), and I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `DO`...`END` block but I just took it out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.SumASCII(
    value character varying)
    RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $function$

DECLARE
    finalResult int := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(value) LOOP
       finalResult := finalResult + ASCII(SUBSTRING(value, i, 1));
    END LOOP;
    RETURN finalResult;
END;
$function$;
```

`SELECT SumASCII('abc')` is returning `294`

Comment: The language name is an identifier, it should not be quoted with single quotes: `language plpgsql` is correct (the single quotes are only accepted for backward compatibility)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, good eye. I skipped over the CREATE portion and went for the body.

Answer (score 1):

The Fortran style is style in PLpgSQL is bad style - any expression is `SELECT`. More embedded `SELECT`s, more slow. What can be done by simple one SQL should be done by simple SQL (it is not true in 100% cases (can depends on individual expressions) - for example @mike.k code is 3x faster than my: there is only one simple expression in cycle, my code has one generic query and very slow regexpr function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sumascii(varchar)
RETURNS bigint AS $$
  SELECT sum(ascii(c)) FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,'') g(c);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

The identifier in SQL (and PostgreSQL too) are not case sensitive, so is not good to use camel notation.

When the result of function is immutable in time (for given argument), then the function should be marked as `IMMUTABLE`.